# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound error when making a python virtual environment

Tags: python, flask, virtual-environment

so I have made a website using Flask which was working perfectly fine until today when I tried to create a python virtual environment. Does anyone know what could have happened? This is the code for my python file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='html_scripts')

@app.route('/home/')
def home():
    return render_template('html_scripts')

@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template('html_scripts')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

This is the code for my main html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Flask App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Adrian's web app</h1>
        <strong><nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav></strong>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        {%block content%}
        {%endblock%}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And these are the remaining 2 files(home_page.html and about.html):

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}
{%block content%}
<div class = 'home'>
    <h1>My homepage</h1>
   <p>This is my homepage</p>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

and,

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}
{%block content%}
<div class = 'about'>
    <h1>My about page</h1>
    <p>This is my about page</p>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

Please do help if you kow how because I have not seen anyone with this problem yet and I can't solve it myself.
Thanks!

Comment: We need more information - Where do you get the error? What route are you trying to access that gives the error? Are you able to start up the virtual env successfully? How are you invoking the App/Flask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `render_template`, try using the actual `html` files. The code below fixes your problem

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='html_scripts')

@app.route('/home/')
def home():
    return render_template('/home_page.html')

@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template('/about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: this did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If use virtual environment You must :

1. first active virtual environment
2. go to directory `app.py` file
3. run `python app.py`

For example: my project flask in this path `D:\MyProjects\MyflaskApp` first active virtualEnviorment then :

```
(my_env) E:\virtualEnc> cd "D:\MyProjects\MyflaskApp"
(my_env) D:\MyProjects\MyflaskApp>python app.py
* Serving Flask app '__name__'
* Debug mode: off
```

app.py :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```